# What's the logic of Compare-Object used in line by line comparison case

Tags: powershell

I have the following csv files:

```
csv file 1               csv file 2
------------             ------------ 
1,2,3,4,5                1,2,3,4,6
a,b,c,d,e                11,12,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e                11,122,3,4,15
a,b,c,d,e                01,2,3,4,6
a,b,c,d,e
11,12,3,4,5
11,12,3,4,15
01,2,3,4,5
```

I used the following command to do a comparison:

```
compare-object (gc test1.csv) (gc test2.csv) -SyncWindow 1
```

and the output is :

```
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
1,2,3,4,6                                                   =>
1,2,3,4,5                                                   <=
11,12,3,4,5                                                 =>
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
11,122,3,4,15                                               =>
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
11,12,3,4,5                                                 <=
11,12,3,4,15                                                <=
01,2,3,4,6                                                  =>
01,2,3,4,5                                                  <=
```

It looks like for the first 3 lines the command just do the comparison line-by-line, and then it continues with the lines only exist in file 1, and at last do the comparison for the line `01,2,3,4,6`

I just wonder why it not continue with the forth line after it processes the first 3 lines, is there any rules for it to consider `01,2,3,4,6` in file 2 is similar to `01,2,3,4,5` in file 1? If so why the output is not:

```
InputObject                                                 SideIndicator
-----------                                                 -------------
1,2,3,4,6                                                   =>
1,2,3,4,5                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
a,b,c,d,e                                                   <=
11,12,3,4,5                                                 =>
11,12,3,4,5                                                 <=
11,122,3,4,15                                               =>
11,12,3,4,15                                                <=
01,2,3,4,6                                                  =>
01,2,3,4,5                                                  <=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using the SyncWindow parameter, that is why the command acts "weird". The [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) documentation describes the function of the parameter as such:

> **-SyncWindow`<Int32>`**
>   Specifies the number of adjacent objects that Compare-Object inspects while looking for an match in a collection of objects. Compare-Object examines adjacent objects when it doesn't find the object in the same position in a collection. The default value is [Int32]::MaxValue, which means that Compare-Object examines the entire object collection.

If you omit the parameter the command compares the objects as expected.

But when looking at the example with the parameter I don't see any logical explanation why.

Answer (score 3):

[`Compare-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113286) with `-SyncWindow 1` is moving a 1-object window through both files.

- To begin with, each line in file 1 is compared with the corresponding line in file 2 but, since the files have different lengths, the window for file 2 stops moving when it reaches the last line.
- From then on, as the window for file 1 continues to move, each line in file 1 is compared with the last line in file 2.
- When the end of file 1 is reached, the last object for both file 1 and file 2 are output.